# swift cannot subscript a value of type [String: DataModelBase.Type] with an index of 'String'

Tags: swift

I'm just starting swift and am trying to replicate functionality I've used with obj-c.  basically it's a json to object model mapping.  the code I'm using looks like it should work, but I'm getting the error in the title and am not sure why or how to fix it.

Here's some sample code:

```
struct foo {
  let modelMap = ["DataModelBase" : DataModelBase.self,
                  "ManifestDataModel" : ManifestDataModel.self]

func createModel(classString: String, json: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> AnyObject {
  if let modelClass: DataModelBase = modelMap[classString] {
    let model = modelClass.initWithDictionary(json)
    return model
  }
  return json
}
```

The error is being triggered on the line:
    if let modelClass: DataModelBase = modelMap[classString]

DataModelBase is a base class and ManifestDataModel subclasses DataModelBase

Can someone shed some light on why the error message is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want in that `if let` statement is probably

```
if let modelClass: DataModelBase = modelMap[classString] as? DataModelBase {
```

this will only run if `modelMap[classString]` is a `DataModelBase`

EDIT:

```
class DataModelBase {
    required init(json: [String:AnyObject]) {

    }
}

class ManifestDataModel: DataModelBase {
    required init(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
        super.init(json: json)
    }
}

struct foo {
    let modelMap = ["DataModelBase" : DataModelBase.self,
        "ManifestDataModel" : ManifestDataModel.self]

    func createModel(classString: String, json: [String: AnyObject]) -> AnyObject {
        if modelMap[classString] != nil {
            if let modelType = modelMap[classString] {
                let model = modelType.init(json: json)
                return model
            }
        }
        return json
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to that, but now I get a warning "Cast from DataModelBase.Type? to unrelated type 'DataModelBase' always fails". If I change it to as? DataModelBase.Type I get the error "Downcast from 'DataModelBase.Type?' to DataModelBase.Type' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: thanks for your help, but hrmm... now that gives me "Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' to expected argument type 'DataModelBase'

Comment: Sorry for being a bit late with this but I tried to build the updated code above and that seems to work fine. Hope this works for you